d3js zoom and pan only works when mouse already over an element in svg
In my angularjs project I used d3js to build a collapsible tree, I used the code provided here.
Now I'm trying to add some simple zoom and pan functionality:
var initZoom = function () {
   var zoom = d3.zoom().extent([[0, 0], [width, height]]).scaleExtent([0.25, 10]).on('zoom', handleZoom);

   d3.select('#d3zoom').call(zoom);
};

var handleZoom = function (e) {
   d3.select('#d3zoom').attr('transform', e.transform);
};

The HTML:
<div id="d3">
   <svg id="d3svg">
      <g id="d3zoom"></g>
   </svg>
</div>

this works but only when my mouse cursor is already hovering over an item (like a node or a link) in the svg. However what I want is to be able to pan and zoom regardless of where my mouse cursor is as long as it is over the svg and so far I've been unable to figure out how.

You should create the zoom (and its event handlers) on the svg and then apply the zoom transform  to a g that wraps  your elements.  A g element, without tricks, doesn't have pointer-events.
var initZoom = function () {
   var zoom = d3.zoom().extent([[0, 0], [width, height]]).scaleExtent([0.25, 10]).on('zoom', handleZoom);

   d3.select('#d3svg').call(zoom); //<-- create here
};

var handleZoom = function (e) {
   d3.select('#d3zoom').attr('transform', e.transform);
};

Running code:


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.9.0/d3.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <svg></svg>
    <script>
      // Specify the charts’ dimensions. The height is variable, depending on the layout.
      const width = 928;
      const height = 500;
      const marginTop = 10;
      const marginRight = 10;
      const marginBottom = 10;
      const marginLeft = 40;

      // Rows are separated by dx pixels, columns by dy pixels. These names can be counter-intuitive
      // (dx is a height, and dy a width). This because the tree must be viewed with the root at the
      // “bottom”, in the data domain. The width of a column is based on the tree’s height.
      const data = {
        name: 'flare',
        children: [
          {
            name: 'analytics',
            children: [
              {
                name: 'cluster',
                children: [
                  { name: 'AgglomerativeCluster', value: 3938 },
                  { name: 'CommunityStructure', value: 3812 },
                  { name: 'HierarchicalCluster', value: 6714 },
                  { name: 'MergeEdge', value: 743 },
                ],
              },
              {
                name: 'graph',
                children: [
                  { name: 'BetweennessCentrality', value: 3534 },
                  { name: 'LinkDistance', value: 5731 },
                  { name: 'MaxFlowMinCut', value: 7840 },
                  { name: 'ShortestPaths', value: 5914 },
                  { name: 'SpanningTree', value: 3416 },
                ],
              },
              {
                name: 'optimization',
                children: [{ name: 'AspectRatioBanker', value: 7074 }],
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            name: 'animate',
            children: [
              { name: 'Easing', value: 17010 },
              { name: 'FunctionSequence', value: 5842 },
              {
                name: 'interpolate',
                children: [
                  { name: 'ArrayInterpolator', value: 1983 },
                  { name: 'ColorInterpolator', value: 2047 },
                  { name: 'DateInterpolator', value: 1375 },
                  { name: 'Interpolator', value: 8746 },
                  { name: 'MatrixInterpolator', value: 2202 },
                  { name: 'NumberInterpolator', value: 1382 },
                  { name: 'ObjectInterpolator', value: 1629 },
                  { name: 'PointInterpolator', value: 1675 },
                  { name: 'RectangleInterpolator', value: 2042 },
                ],
              },
              { name: 'ISchedulable', value: 1041 },
              { name: 'Parallel', value: 5176 },
              { name: 'Pause', value: 449 },
              { name: 'Scheduler', value: 5593 },
              { name: 'Sequence', value: 5534 },
              { name: 'Transition', value: 9201 },
              { name: 'Transitioner', value: 19975 },
              { name: 'TransitionEvent', value: 1116 },
              { name: 'Tween', value: 6006 },
            ],
          },
          {
            name: 'data',
            children: [
              {
                name: 'converters',
                children: [
                  { name: 'Converters', value: 721 },
                  { name: 'DelimitedTextConverter', value: 4294 },
                  { name: 'GraphMLConverter', value: 9800 },
                  { name: 'IDataConverter', value: 1314 },
                  { name: 'JSONConverter', value: 2220 },
                ],
              },
              { name: 'DataField', value: 1759 },
              { name: 'DataSchema', value: 2165 },
              { name: 'DataSet', value: 586 },
              { name: 'DataSource', value: 3331 },
              { name: 'DataTable', value: 772 },
              { name: 'DataUtil', value: 3322 },
            ],
          },
          {
            name: 'display',
            children: [
              { name: 'DirtySprite', value: 8833 },
              { name: 'LineSprite', value: 1732 },
              { name: 'RectSprite', value: 3623 },
              { name: 'TextSprite', value: 10066 },
            ],
          },
          { name: 'flex', children: [{ name: 'FlareVis', value: 4116 }] },
          {
            name: 'physics',
            children: [
              { name: 'DragForce', value: 1082 },
              { name: 'GravityForce', value: 1336 },
              { name: 'IForce', value: 319 },
              { name: 'NBodyForce', value: 10498 },
              { name: 'Particle', value: 2822 },
              { name: 'Simulation', value: 9983 },
              { name: 'Spring', value: 2213 },
              { name: 'SpringForce', value: 1681 },
            ],
          },
          {
            name: 'query',
            children: [
              { name: 'AggregateExpression', value: 1616 },
              { name: 'And', value: 1027 },
              { name: 'Arithmetic', value: 3891 },
              { name: 'Average', value: 891 },
              { name: 'BinaryExpression', value: 2893 },
              { name: 'Comparison', value: 5103 },
              { name: 'CompositeExpression', value: 3677 },
              { name: 'Count', value: 781 },
              { name: 'DateUtil', value: 4141 },
              { name: 'Distinct', value: 933 },
              { name: 'Expression', value: 5130 },
              { name: 'ExpressionIterator', value: 3617 },
              { name: 'Fn', value: 3240 },
              { name: 'If', value: 2732 },
              { name: 'IsA', value: 2039 },
              { name: 'Literal', value: 1214 },
              { name: 'Match', value: 3748 },
              { name: 'Maximum', value: 843 },
              {
                name: 'methods',
                children: [
                  { name: 'add', value: 593 },
                  { name: 'and', value: 330 },
                  { name: 'average', value: 287 },
                  { name: 'count', value: 277 },
                  { name: 'distinct', value: 292 },
                  { name: 'div', value: 595 },
                  { name: 'eq', value: 594 },
                  { name: 'fn', value: 460 },
                  { name: 'gt', value: 603 },
                  { name: 'gte', value: 625 },
                  { name: 'iff', value: 748 },
                  { name: 'isa', value: 461 },
                  { name: 'lt', value: 597 },
                  { name: 'lte', value: 619 },
                  { name: 'max', value: 283 },
                  { name: 'min', value: 283 },
                  { name: 'mod', value: 591 },
                  { name: 'mul', value: 603 },
                  { name: 'neq', value: 599 },
                  { name: 'not', value: 386 },
                  { name: 'or', value: 323 },
                  { name: 'orderby', value: 307 },
                  { name: 'range', value: 772 },
                  { name: 'select', value: 296 },
                  { name: 'stddev', value: 363 },
                  { name: 'sub', value: 600 },
                  { name: 'sum', value: 280 },
                  { name: 'update', value: 307 },
                  { name: 'variance', value: 335 },
                  { name: 'where', value: 299 },
                  { name: 'xor', value: 354 },
                  { name: '_', value: 264 },
                ],
              },
              { name: 'Minimum', value: 843 },
              { name: 'Not', value: 1554 },
              { name: 'Or', value: 970 },
              { name: 'Query', value: 13896 },
              { name: 'Range', value: 1594 },
              { name: 'StringUtil', value: 4130 },
              { name: 'Sum', value: 791 },
              { name: 'Variable', value: 1124 },
              { name: 'Variance', value: 1876 },
              { name: 'Xor', value: 1101 },
            ],
          },
          {
            name: 'scale',
            children: [
              { name: 'IScaleMap', value: 2105 },
              { name: 'LinearScale', value: 1316 },
              { name: 'LogScale', value: 3151 },
              { name: 'OrdinalScale', value: 3770 },
              { name: 'QuantileScale', value: 2435 },
              { name: 'QuantitativeScale', value: 4839 },
              { name: 'RootScale', value: 1756 },
              { name: 'Scale', value: 4268 },
              { name: 'ScaleType', value: 1821 },
              { name: 'TimeScale', value: 5833 },
            ],
          },
          {
            name: 'util',
            children: [
              { name: 'Arrays', value: 8258 },
              { name: 'Colors', value: 10001 },
              { name: 'Dates', value: 8217 },
              { name: 'Displays', value: 12555 },
              { name: 'Filter', value: 2324 },
              { name: 'Geometry', value: 10993 },
              {
                name: 'heap',
                children: [
                  { name: 'FibonacciHeap', value: 9354 },
                  { name: 'HeapNode', value: 1233 },
                ],
              },
              { name: 'IEvaluable', value: 335 },
              { name: 'IPredicate', value: 383 },
              { name: 'IValueProxy', value: 874 },
              {
                name: 'math',
                children: [
                  { name: 'DenseMatrix', value: 3165 },
                  { name: 'IMatrix', value: 2815 },
                  { name: 'SparseMatrix', value: 3366 },
                ],
              },
              { name: 'Maths', value: 17705 },
              { name: 'Orientation', value: 1486 },
              {
                name: 'palette',
                children: [
                  { name: 'ColorPalette', value: 6367 },
                  { name: 'Palette', value: 1229 },
                  { name: 'ShapePalette', value: 2059 },
                  { name: 'SizePalette', value: 2291 },
                ],
              },
              { name: 'Property', value: 5559 },
              { name: 'Shapes', value: 19118 },
              { name: 'Sort', value: 6887 },
              { name: 'Stats', value: 6557 },
              { name: 'Strings', value: 22026 },
            ],
          },
          {
            name: 'vis',
            children: [
              {
                name: 'axis',
                children: [
                  { name: 'Axes', value: 1302 },
                  { name: 'Axis', value: 24593 },
                  { name: 'AxisGridLine', value: 652 },
                  { name: 'AxisLabel', value: 636 },
                  { name: 'CartesianAxes', value: 6703 },
                ],
              },
              {
                name: 'controls',
                children: [
                  { name: 'AnchorControl', value: 2138 },
                  { name: 'ClickControl', value: 3824 },
                  { name: 'Control', value: 1353 },
                  { name: 'ControlList', value: 4665 },
                  { name: 'DragControl', value: 2649 },
                  { name: 'ExpandControl', value: 2832 },
                  { name: 'HoverControl', value: 4896 },
                  { name: 'IControl', value: 763 },
                  { name: 'PanZoomControl', value: 5222 },
                  { name: 'SelectionControl', value: 7862 },
                  { name: 'TooltipControl', value: 8435 },
                ],
              },
              {
                name: 'data',
                children: [
                  { name: 'Data', value: 20544 },
                  { name: 'DataList', value: 19788 },
                  { name: 'DataSprite', value: 10349 },
                  { name: 'EdgeSprite', value: 3301 },
                  { name: 'NodeSprite', value: 19382 },
                  {
                    name: 'render',
                    children: [
                      { name: 'ArrowType', value: 698 },
                      { name: 'EdgeRenderer', value: 5569 },
                      { name: 'IRenderer', value: 353 },
                      { name: 'ShapeRenderer', value: 2247 },
                    ],
                  },
                  { name: 'ScaleBinding', value: 11275 },
                  { name: 'Tree', value: 7147 },
                  { name: 'TreeBuilder', value: 9930 },
                ],
              },
              {
                name: 'events',
                children: [
                  { name: 'DataEvent', value: 2313 },
                  { name: 'SelectionEvent', value: 1880 },
                  { name: 'TooltipEvent', value: 1701 },
                  { name: 'VisualizationEvent', value: 1117 },
                ],
              },
              {
                name: 'legend',
                children: [
                  { name: 'Legend', value: 20859 },
                  { name: 'LegendItem', value: 4614 },
                  { name: 'LegendRange', value: 10530 },
                ],
              },
              {
                name: 'operator',
                children: [
                  {
                    name: 'distortion',
                    children: [
                      { name: 'BifocalDistortion', value: 4461 },
                      { name: 'Distortion', value: 6314 },
                      { name: 'FisheyeDistortion', value: 3444 },
                    ],
                  },
                  {
                    name: 'encoder',
                    children: [
                      { name: 'ColorEncoder', value: 3179 },
                      { name: 'Encoder', value: 4060 },
                      { name: 'PropertyEncoder', value: 4138 },
                      { name: 'ShapeEncoder', value: 1690 },
                      { name: 'SizeEncoder', value: 1830 },
                    ],
                  },
                  {
                    name: 'filter',
                    children: [
                      { name: 'FisheyeTreeFilter', value: 5219 },
                      { name: 'GraphDistanceFilter', value: 3165 },
                      { name: 'VisibilityFilter', value: 3509 },
                    ],
                  },
                  { name: 'IOperator', value: 1286 },
                  {
                    name: 'label',
                    children: [
                      { name: 'Labeler', value: 9956 },
                      { name: 'RadialLabeler', value: 3899 },
                      { name: 'StackedAreaLabeler', value: 3202 },
                    ],
                  },
                  {
                    name: 'layout',
                    children: [
                      { name: 'AxisLayout', value: 6725 },
                      { name: 'BundledEdgeRouter', value: 3727 },
                      { name: 'CircleLayout', value: 9317 },
                      { name: 'CirclePackingLayout', value: 12003 },
                      { name: 'DendrogramLayout', value: 4853 },
                      { name: 'ForceDirectedLayout', value: 8411 },
                      { name: 'IcicleTreeLayout', value: 4864 },
                      { name: 'IndentedTreeLayout', value: 3174 },
                      { name: 'Layout', value: 7881 },
                      { name: 'NodeLinkTreeLayout', value: 12870 },
                      { name: 'PieLayout', value: 2728 },
                      { name: 'RadialTreeLayout', value: 12348 },
                      { name: 'RandomLayout', value: 870 },
                      { name: 'StackedAreaLayout', value: 9121 },
                      { name: 'TreeMapLayout', value: 9191 },
                    ],
                  },
                  { name: 'Operator', value: 2490 },
                  { name: 'OperatorList', value: 5248 },
                  { name: 'OperatorSequence', value: 4190 },
                  { name: 'OperatorSwitch', value: 2581 },
                  { name: 'SortOperator', value: 2023 },
                ],
              },
              { name: 'Visualization', value: 16540 },
            ],
          },
        ],
      };
      const root = d3.hierarchy(data);
      const dx = 10;
      const dy = (width - marginRight - marginLeft) / (1 + root.height);

      // Define the tree layout and the shape for links.
      const tree = d3.tree().nodeSize([dx, dy]);
      const diagonal = d3
        .linkHorizontal()
        .x((d) => d.y)
        .y((d) => d.x);

      // Create the SVG container, a layer for the links and a layer for the nodes.
      const svg = d3
        .select('svg')
        .attr('width', width)
        .attr('height', height)
        .attr('height', dx)
        .attr('viewBox', [-marginLeft, -marginTop, width, dx])
        .attr(
          'style',
          'max-width: 100%; height: auto; font: 10px sans-serif; user-select: none;'
        );

      const zoom_g = svg.append('g');

      const gLink = zoom_g
        .append('g')
        .attr('fill', 'none')
        .attr('stroke', '#555')
        .attr('stroke-opacity', 0.4)
        .attr('stroke-width', 1.5);

      const gNode = zoom_g
        .append('g')
        .attr('cursor', 'pointer')
        .attr('pointer-events', 'all');

      function update(event, source) {
        const duration = event?.altKey ? 2500 : 250; // hold the alt key to slow down the transition
        const nodes = root.descendants().reverse();
        const links = root.links();

        // Compute the new tree layout.
        tree(root);

        let left = root;
        let right = root;
        root.eachBefore((node) => {
          if (node.x < left.x) left = node;
          if (node.x > right.x) right = node;
        });

        const height = right.x - left.x + marginTop + marginBottom;

        const transition = svg
          .transition()
          .duration(duration)
          .attr('height', height)
          .attr('viewBox', [-marginLeft, left.x - marginTop, width, height])
          .tween(
            'resize',
            window.ResizeObserver ? null : () => () => svg.dispatch('toggle')
          );

        // Update the nodes…
        const node = gNode.selectAll('g').data(nodes, (d) => d.id);

        // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
        const nodeEnter = node
          .enter()
          .append('g')
          .attr('transform', (d) => `translate(${source.y0},${source.x0})`)
          .attr('fill-opacity', 0)
          .attr('stroke-opacity', 0)
          .on('click', (event, d) => {
            d.children = d.children ? null : d._children;
            update(event, d);
          });

        nodeEnter
          .append('circle')
          .attr('r', 2.5)
          .attr('fill', (d) => (d._children ? '#555' : '#999'))
          .attr('stroke-width', 10);

        nodeEnter
          .append('text')
          .attr('dy', '0.31em')
          .attr('x', (d) => (d._children ? -6 : 6))
          .attr('text-anchor', (d) => (d._children ? 'end' : 'start'))
          .text((d) => d.data.name)
          .attr('stroke-linejoin', 'round')
          .attr('stroke-width', 3)
          .attr('stroke', 'white')
          .attr('paint-order', 'stroke');

        // Transition nodes to their new position.
        const nodeUpdate = node
          .merge(nodeEnter)
          .transition(transition)
          .attr('transform', (d) => `translate(${d.y},${d.x})`)
          .attr('fill-opacity', 1)
          .attr('stroke-opacity', 1);

        // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
        const nodeExit = node
          .exit()
          .transition(transition)
          .remove()
          .attr('transform', (d) => `translate(${source.y},${source.x})`)
          .attr('fill-opacity', 0)
          .attr('stroke-opacity', 0);

        // Update the links…
        const link = gLink.selectAll('path').data(links, (d) => d.target.id);

        // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
        const linkEnter = link
          .enter()
          .append('path')
          .attr('d', (d) => {
            const o = { x: source.x0, y: source.y0 };
            return diagonal({ source: o, target: o });
          });

        // Transition links to their new position.
        link.merge(linkEnter).transition(transition).attr('d', diagonal);

        // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
        link
          .exit()
          .transition(transition)
          .remove()
          .attr('d', (d) => {
            const o = { x: source.x, y: source.y };
            return diagonal({ source: o, target: o });
          });

        // Stash the old positions for transition.
        root.eachBefore((d) => {
          d.x0 = d.x;
          d.y0 = d.y;
        });
      }

      // Do the first update to the initial configuration of the tree — where a number of nodes
      // are open (arbitrarily selected as the root, plus nodes with 7 letters).
      root.x0 = dy / 2;
      root.y0 = 0;
      root.descendants().forEach((d, i) => {
        d.id = i;
        d._children = d.children;
        if (d.depth && d.data.name.length !== 7) d.children = null;
      });

      update(null, root);

      const handleZoom = function (e) {
        zoom_g.attr('transform', e.transform);
      };

      var zoom = d3
        .zoom()
        .extent([
          [0, 0],
          [width, height],
        ])
        .scaleExtent([0.25, 10])
        .on('zoom', handleZoom);

      svg.call(zoom);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>



